# vc9 error 4430 on one machine, not on the other

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++-2008

Compiling the same code on two different machines. We have int functions that are not explicitly defined as such in the CPP file.

One machine compiles fine, the other doesn't. What's really weird is that they were both working fine until yesterday. One of the machines lost its visual studio include and link paths and now the compile is being much fussier.

What should we be looking for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the issue. An add-on product must have had the disable:4430 in its header files. At some point that paths to that was lost and it was loading an older version.

thanks!